# 1.9 Custom Spawn Egg riding, area cloud?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is it possible to summon creatures riding other creatures with a spawn egg, and is it possible to create spawn eggs that summon non-standard things such as Primed TNT or AreaEffect Clouds?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can make creatures riding others with spawn eggs but spawn eggs can contain any entity even though it won't work for anything other than mobs or animals. Like you can give yourself a "Spawn Dragon Fireball" egg if you want but it won't do anything.

The model for the give command is

```
/give [playername] minecraft:spawn_egg 1 0 {EntityTag:{id:"[EntityID]"}}
```

You can find a list of EntityID at this address: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk_format